# Is it possible to use vectorized ifelse to change the character into numeric?

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization

I would like to convert the characters into numeric.

1->1 ,2->2 ,...,10->10 ,10+->11

At first, I tried to use if else and for loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(a)){
     if(a[i] == "10+"){
        a[i] = 11} else
        {a[i] = as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(a[i],"\\d+"))
        }
}
```

Then, I tried to use vectorized ifelse:

```
ifelse(a== "10+",11, 
      (as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(a[i],"\\d+"))))
```

How can I rewrite `as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(a[i],"\\d+")))` part? Please provide some suggestion

The sample dataset:

| a (char) |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 10+ |
| 10+ |

Expected outcome:

| a (int) |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 11 |

Comment: There are a few ways to handle this problem, but if you want to use `ifelse()`, perhaps `a_char <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 10, "10+", "10+"); a_int <- ifelse(!is.na(as.integer(a_char)), as.integer(a_char), as.integer(11))` would work?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with this simple code

```
a[a=="10+"] <- "11"
a <- as.numeric(a)
```